my problem is what does arm of heat mean?
Could you help me to find meaning of "arm of heat" ???
thank you!

Context - perhaps an excerpt from the source - would be helpful.

Figurative Language in "Lord of the Flies":  "Arm of heat" is a metaphor from Lord of the Flies by William Golding that compares the fire's heat and dancing flames to the aggressive movement of an outstretched human arm. In the book, the phrase appears in Chapter 2, "Fire on the Mountain". But this question belongs on SO Literature under "Identify this book".

Please do not post questions like this without providing the origin of the phrase or where you saw it.
